Unable to stop Locust as Greenlet/Gevent error found causing state to stuck at CleanUp
We are using Locust to run performance tests on our FastAPI endpoints on Google Cloud Platform. Intermittently, we encounter an issue that would not allow us to stop the test due to an error related to Greenlet/Gevent as soon as we click the "Stop" button. Locust will get stuck at the CleanUp stage while the requests are continue being sent.
We find that this error will have a higher chance to occur when we set up larger concurrent peak users and higher spawn rate. It will almost certainly occur if we set 300 peak users and 100 spawn rate.
Also we did not run anything at on_stop()
The error logs:
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.594432Z Exception ignored in: <finalize object at 0x3ef2919c3b20; dead>
ERROR 2024-05-09T16:01:22.595503Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 590, in __call__ return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.595511Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.595517Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1133, in _close_pool_connections
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.597778Z conn = pool.get(block=False)
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.597844Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.597855Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 182, in get
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.598757Z self.not_full.notify()
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.598854Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 369, in notify
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.600847Z if not self._is_owned():
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.600879Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.600883Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 282, in _is_owned
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.601021Z if self._lock.acquire(False):
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.601056Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.601060Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/thread.py", line 132, in acquire
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.604530Z sleep()
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.604547Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 159, in sleep
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.606630Z waiter.get()
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.606674Z File "src/gevent/_waiter.py", line 143, in gevent._gevent_c_waiter.Waiter.get
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.606865Z File "src/gevent/_waiter.py", line 154, in gevent._gevent_c_waiter.Waiter.get
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.606906Z File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 61, in gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.606963Z File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 61, in gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.607023Z File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 65, in gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.607071Z File "src/gevent/_gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.pxd", line 35, in gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives._greenlet_switch
DEFAULT 2024-05-09T16:01:22.607131Z greenlet.GreenletExit:

We have found this bug issue that looks very similar to our case and therefore have updated locust to 2.17.0, but the issue still persist.
https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/2401
Tried fixes:

Update locust to 2.17.0
Update locust to 2.27.0
Update gevent to 24.2.1

Updates
A minimised locustfile that can reproduce the bug:
import google.oauth2.id_token
from config import config
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

BASE_URL = config.BASE_URL


def set_header():
    """Set header for SDS requests"""
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    auth_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(
        auth_req, audience=config.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
    )
    return {"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"}

HEADERS = set_header()

class PerformanceTests(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2)
    host = config.BASE_URL

    # Test unit data endpoint
    @task
    def http_get_data_v1(self):
        self.client.get(
            f"{config.BASE_URL}/v1/unit_data?dataset_id=2cf4e4e6-ba69-4935-bf57-7b72c7bc2a32&identifier={config.FIXED_IDENTIFIERS[0]}",
            headers=HEADERS,
        )


The Locust Log:
[2024-05-13 12:59:23,139] localhost/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089
[2024-05-13 12:59:23,157] localhost/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.27.0
[2024-05-13 12:59:40,825] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 200 users at a rate of 100.00 per second
[2024-05-13 12:59:42,847] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"PerformanceTests": 200} (200 total users)
[2024-05-13 13:00:34,706] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 200 users at a rate of 100.00 per second
[2024-05-13 13:00:36,820] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"PerformanceTests": 200} (200 total users)
[2024-05-13 13:01:05,715] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 200 users at a rate of 100.00 per second
[2024-05-13 13:01:07,766] localhost/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"PerformanceTests": 200} (200 total users)


Hi! Can you share your locustfile? Remove as much as possible while still being able to reproduce the issue (with latest Locust version).

Also can you share the full log and command line?

@Cyberwiz Thanks for helping. I have added our locustfile and full log in the post. Error will always occur when we ramp concurrent users to >200 and spawn rate >100 and we run Locust on Google Cloud

What is your command line for starting locust? Does it really make sense to authenticate before each request? Is google.auth.transport.requests.Request() thread/gevent safe?

also, those logs look strange to me? I'm asking for the locust logs. Typically they look something like this: [2024-05-12 22:49:38,032] <your-machine-name>/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.27.0

Hi. We don't use a command line to start Locust as we use the WebUI. And sorry about the confusion, I have included the Locust logs of our latest tests (Locust hang at Cleanup at the 3rd time of the test), and we have set it to run auth only at start.
